# Social Implication of Restricting Ecosystem

Tags: society, culture, alternate-worlds, cities

Assuming a world with multiple (more than ten) competing sapient species, and assuming that some of these species are restricted to certain ecological conditions, how would one expect political and cultural borders to develop? I am *not* looking for a traditional 'one race-one nation' fantasy world map. Instead I'm interested in the possibility of multiple, different species interacting with each other as a single culture, one of several cultures in the geographical region, some of which are more diverse than others.

Given this premise: what would be the effect of demographics on urban planning? What about road building, shipping, transport, and trade? Is it plausible for different species to occupy the different social strata more or less equally, or does a mixed society necessarily lead to one group's interests being held as the highest priority? Would certain roles or careers gravitate to certain groups, based on their physical characteristics? Not just in terms of the largest/strongest being foot soldiers, but beyond that.

What about a civilization developing in a very restrictive physical environment? A particularly harsh desert, for example, or at a dangerously high altitude. Would cultures like this necessarily be isolationist, and if they are, would they necessarily be xenophobic/hostile?

Comment: Unfortunately I think this question is just too broad to be effectively answered at the moment. You need to break it down into a much more specific question to get started. For example talk about one city with three races and describe the difference between the races...or talk just about roles and careers or just the restrictive physical environment....I can see 5 or 6 good questions inside this one but at the moment it's just not possible to answer any of them properly as there are too many questions mixed together.

Comment: I can see your point. I guess if I try to isolate the different variables, the middle paragraph is what I'm focused on. Given that there is already one answer, should I trim out the other parts and set them aside for (potentially) other questions? It might make the answer seem completely out of context.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea to me, I wouldn't worry too much about the answer. It can also be edited down or split over the questions as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**Communities**

I'm going to suggest that the answers to this lies in the immigration patterns of our own world. In my limited experience I find that when a group of people move into a new city or area they tend to stay as a community within the larger city. After all people like to be with people they associate themselves with.

An example of this would be the various chinatowns in may cities across the world or the largely Eastern European, Indian or Arabic communities you find in many UK cities (and I assume elsewhere). Mexicans in the US?

As I hinted at above many people prefer to live with people with a similar social background, this is why you tend to get these vibrant mini communities within the larger communities which make up a city.

As a result I would suggest that in your world the fact that these people are different species would make little difference. You would have communities in each city made up of the different species - sure there would be crossovers. Perhaps a particularly well off person from one species would like to live among the more affluent neighbors, race is not the only community.

**Work**

Oh how this section has the potential to be politically incorrect... I've done my best!

I believe some races would be better suited to different jobs, there may be some evolutionary edge (avian races will clearly be better suited to working at height) but often this will also be an element of tradition.

Many of the first immigrants from China and India into the UK brought their unique style of food with them, they opened restaurants and have built very successful businesses bringing their culture to another part of the world. It's a very traditional job for the first immigrants into a new town or city.

There are many family and community traditions which push young people towards certain professions. Minority communities are often highly represented in respected roles such as doctors, many other communities value running their own businesses and you have a high proportion of shop and business owners.

These affinities are often not due to any evolutionary edge (after all suggesting that someone was a better doctor because they or their parents were born in a different country is madness). However the values of a community can go a long way to guiding people's career paths (for example where I grew up everyone a massive number of my peers went to work on the family farm or take on very skilled practical jobs such as joinery or construction. Honest hard work is valued very highly).

**Public Areas**

In terms of public areas, buildings and urban planning I believe this will be largely subject to your world and the species in it. Depending on the physical requirements and the culture of the nations will determine how these issues are addressed.

Firstly you need to decide whether all species are treated equally. If so then I'd suggest that furniture, buildings and conveniences will be designed to be as widely accessible as possible. Where this is not possible there may be segregation, different bathrooms for example. There is no reason why there may be different areas where cultures are VERY different!

If your nation regards some species as second class citizens then life will be very segregated. Think back to some of the black/white divides we've seen in the past. Everything will be split from transport to meeting rooms and possibly even companies refusing to serve clients of a particular species. I don't think I can add much more without knowing the public attitudes to the different races.

**Isolationism**

I'm going to touch on this one although I feel it could spiral out and become far too broad. I don't believe a culture developing in an isolated area would be particularly prone to xenophobia. Many isolated cultures and villages are often very welcoming to outsiders. However this will depend on the nature of their early contacts. I'll leave it there, this section could span questions in itself!